# Powering same LED strip from 2 drivers - diode?

Tags: led, 12v, lighting

So I'm looking at adding some LED mood lighting to our bedroom.
End game is to have a single LED strip controlled by 2 different switches

Currently, I have 2 switched 240V AC outlets, one either side of the bed, with each one feeding a 12v DC LED driver.
From this, I've got a short LED strip at bedside height. This works fine, as the left switch controls the left lights, and vice-versa.

I'd now like to add a strip at high-level, that is turned on when *either* side is switched on... 
I can take a feed from both drivers to the strip, however I suspect that if I just wire the LED strip into both drivers, then if I power on one side, then the power will leach through to the other side.

What's the best way to prevent this? A quick google suggests using a Diode, however I'm struggling to pick out the best option.
Is something like a [SB560](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor-Fairchild/SB560?qs=mVVXn4M53U%2FtgCVD382p0w==) the right choice? Or should I be looking for something different?

Cheers in advance for any replies.

Comment: FYI The part number you gave is obsolete. Try 6A06 or 6A10 from Digikey/Mouser, etc. These are 6 Amp 600/1000 volt and are trusted by many.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feiCtq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you get some kind of weird behavior, switch the direction of the diodes and put them on the "positive" side - most LED drivers use "common anode" configuration which means the LED's are tied to the positive rail, and the negative (cathode) side is switched/PWM'd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you know the diodes go between the driver and the LEDs (**not** on the AC side).

And not knowing the LEDs current draw, the 5A spec of the suggested diode might be OK.  Do you know the current draw?

Also, the diode presence will create a voltage drop - that gets worse with current (see spec sheet) so the LEDs might not operate normally (dimmer)

Comment: Yeh, I'm intending on the Diode on the DC side of the driver.

I've currently got a 50cm strip at low level, and the LED strip is rated at 12W/meter max. So worst case 0.5A per side currently...   
The high-level strip will be ~2.5m, so that's another 2.5A, so that's 3A per driver total... 

Dimming of the LEDs isn't a bad thing, as it's intended to be accent lighting rather than the main source.

Comment: Sounds like it's worth a try